# Where does Hybris set/generate versionID for orders?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Wondering if anyone can tell me where/how Hybris is generating versionIDs for orders on amendment etc

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Order *VersionID* is generated in the `DefaultOrderHistoryService.createHistorySnapshot(OrderModel)` using the `KeyGenerator`

The versionID is assigned to the order in case of order cancellation, return or replacement.

The full reference to the Service ; `de.hybris.platform.orderhistory.impl.DefaultOrderHistoryService`

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of maintaining Order History and Order Versioning is to keep track of changes applied to the order which help customer service agents to look what actually happened to a particular order.

**OrderHistoryEntry** is used to store historical information of order processing. This will not create a new version of original order but can have a reference to an order state snapshot.

```
OrderHistoryEntryModel entry = modelService.create(OrderHistoryEntryModel.class);
entry.setTimestamp(new Date());
entry.setOrder(processedOrder);
entry.setDescription("fraud check manually passed");
entry.setEmployee( (EmployeeModel)userService.getCurrentUser() );
```

To keep the previous order state as historical information requires the creation a snapshot of the order before altering the order. This will create a new version of original order. Each snapshot will contain particular versionID.

```
OrderHistoryService historyService = ..


// create snapshot - not persisted yet !
OrderModel snapshot = historyService.createHistorySnapshot(processedOrder);
```

**The service will produces a deep copy of the original order.**

Now we can save this snapshot in OrderHistoryEntryModel as well.

```
entry.setPreviousOrderVersion(snapshot);
```

We need to manually persist snapshot

```
// persist snapshot manually - this is necessary due to historical reasons
historyService.saveHistorySnapshot(snapshot);
```

Since snapshot is also like order and resides in same table, to fetch all original order, you need to apply `{versionID} IS NULL` condition as well while fetching orders.